# Should I set two different Cloudfront distributions for elb and aws S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, caching, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb

I have a website hosted on aws elastic beanstalk and the images on my website are stored and gotten from an S3 bucket.

I want to set up aws Cloudfront distributions for the website.

My question is, do I set up two different distributions for the elastic load balancer and the S3 bucket that my images are gotten from?

or

if I set up a distribution for only the load balancer, will the images on my website be automatically cached for future use?

Answer (score 0):

Just one Cloudfront distribution will suffice. Use this manual by AWS: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-distribution-serve-content/